"Postman Error: Status 409 Conflict with JavaScript in Response Body During API Login Request"
Problem Description: I'm trying to send a POST request to the login endpoint of my API using Postman, but I keep receiving a 409 Conflict error with JavaScript code in the response body. The response contains the following HTML:
<script>
  document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; 
  document.location.reload(true);
</script>



Check this status 409 explanation, maybe it'll give you an idea about what happen to your API. And sorry, what does this problem have to do with flutter?
